# Check if a string is present in multiple lists (Python)

Tags: python, list

What is the most efficient way to check whether a set string is present in all of three given lists, and if so, set itemInAllLists to True?

Below is the general idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
item = 'test-element'

list_a = ['a','random','test-element']
list_b = ['light','apple','table']
list_c = ['car','field','test-element','chair']

itemInAllLists = False

if item in [list_a] and item in [list_b] and item in [list_c]:
    itemInAllLists = True
```

Check if string present in multiple lists (Python)

Comment: `item in list_a`, not `[list_a]`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) built-in for Python. It will return `True` if all elements of an iterable is true.

If you put all your lists in a combined list, you can do [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to check each list.

```py
all(item in all_lists for all_lists in [list_a, list_b, list_c])
```

As [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) mentions, you don't have to do it this way. What you are doing works as well and might be easier to read. Using `all` or `any` might be better suited for more lists or when you create them dynamically.

For your code to work, you just have to remove the brackets so the syntax is correct:

```py
if item in list_a and item in list_b and item in list_c:
    pass
```

Comment: FWIW, `item in list_a and ...` isn't any longer than this and is possibly easier to comprehend than an `all` here; this would make more sense if there were a lot more lists.